# Why is my JavaScript function to plot all of the different combinations of various numbers stopping after only a few runs

Tags: javascript, arrays, factorial

I'm working on a TSP application that involves plotting various points on a map. I need each possible combination to be plotted once and only once. The code below logically makes sense to me, however it's not getting passed a few turns, which is many, many times fewer than it is meant to.

```
var dogs = [];
var totalDogs = 9;
var prevComps = [];
var count = 0;


function setup() {

  //Define the canvas
  createCanvas(700, 575);

  //Generate a random vector position for each dog
  for (var i = 0; i < totalDogs ; i++){
    var vectorPoints = createVector(random(width), random(height));
    dogs[i] = vectorPoints;
  }
}

function draw() {

  //Sets the background to black and the circles (ellipses) to white
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  for (var i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++){
    ellipse(dogs[i].x, dogs[i].y, 8, 8);
  }

  //Defines the lines/paths
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  noFill();
  beginShape();

  //Draw every dog on the map at their randomly generated vector point
  for (var i = 0; i < dogs.length; i++){
    vertex(dogs[i].x, dogs[i].y);
  }

  endShape();

  //Creates two random numbers within the range of our array and swaps them
  var i = floor(random(dogs.length));
  var j = floor(random(dogs.length));

  //Creates an array, stores the random numbers there to be compared and creates an "isNew" bool to determine if this pair has already been created
  var comp = [];
  comp.push(i);
  comp.push(j);
  var isNew = true;

  //Checks to see if the new combo has been used before and thus stored in our previous comparison array
  for(l = 0; l < prevComps.length; l++){
    if(prevComps[l][0] == comp[0] && prevComp[l][1] == comp[1]){
      isNew = false;
    }
  }

  //If isNew is still true, the combination must be unique and so increase our count, add it to the prevComp array and finally swap the elements
  if(isNew == true){

  count++;    
  prevComps.push(comp);

  //testing purposes
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count;



  swap(dogs, i, j)

  }

}



//Simple swap function
function swap(a, i, j){

  var tempVar = a[i]
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = tempVar;

}
```

I hope I have commented this code ok and it is readable, if not I'd be happy to fill in any blanks. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code in what constitutes a turn? What's calling the draw function? It also may be worth posting some of the functions you have like ellipse, vertex, etc. So we can verify that your canvas draw code is working correctly.

Comment: it looks like `dogs` remains empty, I cannot see anywhere you are pushing into `dogs`. In loops the console.log is useful to keep track of what's going on

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure what is calling the draw function, I'm very new to JS and thought that it was peculiar how the draw function was being called despite it not being actually called anywhere. This is just a javascript script file that is simply linked on an otherwise completely blank index page. It uses the p5 javascript library for the drawing functions you've mentioned

Comment: Dogs gets populated in the code under the "Generate a random vector position for each dog"  comment

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, I think the problem is that you're remembering swaps (in prevComps), rather than full sequences..

So maybe try to work with index arrays - starting with `indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`, draw the line via `dogs[indices[i]]` rather than `dogs[i]`, then swap indices around (instead of modifying `dogs`), then store copies of whole indices in prevComps, rather than just the two numbers (`i` and `j`) which were swapped in one iteration.